# Store array values from multiple input field - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

What I'm trying to do is Schedule form represent in table with input field like day, start time, and end time.

In blade file, I have an array that I assigned values which is represent days (7 in total). The reason I put in array cause I don't want to write html code 7 times. I do FOR loop to display input field with assigned value.

Then, I want to input another value which is 'start time' and 'end time' according to each day.

Below is my code

In blade

```
    <?php
          $days = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Satuday");
          $daylength=count($days);

          for($i=0; $i<$daylength; $i++)
          {
     ?>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="day[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $days[$i] }}" disabled/></td>
            <td><input type="time" name="start_time[]" class="form-control"/></td>
            <td><input type="time" name="end_time[]" class="form-control"/></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

In controller

```
$days = $request->input('day');
$start_time = $request->input('start_time');
$end_time = $request->input('end_time');
$zone_id = $zone->id;

    for($count = 0; $count < count($days); $count++)
    {
        $data = array(
                'day' => $days[$count],
                'start_time'  => $start_time[$count],
                'end_time'  => $end_time[$count],
                'zone_id'  => $zone_id,
              );

        $insert_schedule[] = $data; 
     }
     Schedule::insert($insert_schedule);
```

What I expected, it should store input values into database table. The problem is after submitting the form, controller request empty value.

The error shown :

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable

Hope anyone can help. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: maybe it's not submitting `day` because the input is disabled?

Comment: Yes you're right ! I found the solution from one of the answers below. I should replace "disabled" to "readonly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**disabled** input won't submit. You need to use **readonly** if you want to make it not editable by user.

```
<input type="text" name="day[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $days[$i] }}" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<input type="text" name="day[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $days[$i] }}" disabled/>
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="day[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $days[$i] }}" />
```

Disabled inputs will not submit with the form request.  You'll have to use a different technique if you don't want a user to be able to change the value.  Can it be hidden?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It can't be hidden cause I need to display the days, but I don't want the user make any change on that. Finally found the solution, I must replace "disabled" with "readonly".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $start_time; $i++) {
    foreach ($days as $day) {
      $insert_array[] = array(
      'day' => $day[$i ],
        'start_time'  => $start_time[$i ],
        'end_time'  => $end_time[$i ],
        'zone_id'  => $zone_id,
          );
         }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I replace "disabled" with "readonly" at input (html). It's worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in count() function try :

```
for($count = 0; $count < collect($days)->count(); $count++)
{
    $data = array(
            'day' => $days[$count],
            'start_time'  => $start_time[$count],
            'end_time'  => $end_time[$count],
            'zone_id'  => $zone_id,
          );

    $insert_schedule[] = $data; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I replace "disabled" with "readonly" at input (html). It's worked.